# Document a constant using ngDoc

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc

How would one go about documenting a constant using ngDoc?  I don't see any angular specific documentation for documenting values registered with `.constant`, and the jsDoc syntax for constants doesn't seem to generate any actual docs when it's run through ngDoc.

Ex:

`/**
* @constant
* @name WHITE
*
* @description
* The color white!
**/
module.constant( 'WHITE', '#fff' );`

Answer (score 3):

ngDocs currently doesn't provide a way to document constants. As you can see in its [templating source code](https://github.com/m7r/grunt-ngdocs/blob/a42e2f7befff166d266cd004c21ccd559d2a8b82/src/ngdoc.js#L868). There isnt relevant `html_usage_*` method.

I document constants like this, it shows a APP_CONFIG as a module then.

```
/**
 * @ngdoc object
 * @name APP_CONFIG
 * @description
 *   constant...
 * @example
 * APP_CONFIG is injectable as constant (as a service even to .config())
 * <pre>
 * (...)    .config(function ($APP_CONFIG) {
 * </pre>
 */
```

Comment: Do you know how to document a .run function ?

Answer (score -2):

It should be @const

```
/** @const */ var MY_BEER = 'stout';

/**
 * My namespace's favorite kind of beer.
 * @const {string}
 */
mynamespace.MY_BEER = 'stout';

/** @const */ MyClass.MY_BEER = 'stout';

/**
 * Initializes the request.
 * @const
 */
mynamespace.Request.prototype.initialize = function() {
  // This method cannot be overridden in a subclass.
};
```

See the constant part http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Constants and the comments part http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Comments#Comments for more informations